# Matrix Object in Javascript & Matrix Rotate Function

Tags: javascript, matrix

Is there a native Javascript Matrix object? You know how theres a Date, Array, Object, is there a Matrix?

If not, which 3rd party library is best to use Matrices in Javascript?

Does anyone know of an open source Matrix function that rotates around a point? IE...

```
var myMatrix     = {tx: 1, ty: 0, ...other matrix values};
var rotMatrix    = rotate(myAngle, myMatrix);
var newRectPoint = {x: rotMatrix.tx, y: rotMatrix.ty};
```

Comment: There is no built-in matrix object in Javascript, but there are multi-dimensional arrays.  There are libraries for matrices, but I don't use any, and thus can't name any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use underscore's `zip.apply()` for the purpose.

Refer this for details: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/page/2/

Answer (score 1):

Though still no native math matrix object, there is a famous 3rd party library [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/).

From its [example](http://mathjs.org/examples/matrices.js.html), you can simply create matrix with:

```
var a = math.matrix([1, 4, 9, 16, 25]);
var b = math.matrix(math.ones([2, 3]));
```